# Error with SqlDataAdapter Update

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

Using C#, SQL Server 2016 - Trying to write a method to update every record in a dataset - a single field to a new value - using a `DataAdapter` object, and am getting the following error message:

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information.

Here is my code (a method on a class containing a `DataSet TheDS`, an `SQLDataAdapter TheAdapter`, and a `DataTable TheDataTable`):

```
    public void updateDSField<T>(string fieldName, T newVal)
    {
        // Updates field in dataset

        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(TheAdapter);
        var col = TheDataTable.Columns[fieldName];
        foreach (DataRow row in TheDataTable.Rows) row[col] = newVal;
        TheAdapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
        TheAdapter.Update(TheDS);
    }
```

I read something about the SqlCommandBuilder not being able to handle >1000 rows - is that correct?  Either way, what is the correct way to perform this operation?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Rahul - edited the post; hope this is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to build my own command string, as the builder does not handle more than 1000 rows.  I was worried that this would update the entire table at first, but this link

[C# DataTable Update Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850883/c-sharp-datatable-update-multiple-lines)

put my mind at ease.  (Assuming also I know the table name, `TheTableName`).

```
    public void updateDSField<T>(string fieldName, T newVal)
    {   
        // updates field in dataset

        var col = TheDataTable.Columns[fieldName];
        foreach (DataRow row in TheDataTable.Rows) row[col] = newVal; // * this marks the rows to be update by the commandtext

        // create adapter and update string
        TheAdapter.UpdateCommand = TheConn.CreateCommand();
        string newValString = newVal.ToString();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) newValString = "'" + newValString + "'";
        TheAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [" + TheTableName + "] SET [" + fieldName + "] =" + newValString;

        TheAdapter.Update(TheDS);  // this will only update those rows marked by step * above
    }
```